# ActiveMQ persistance Adapter configuration issue

Tags: activemq-classic

i am new with ActiveMQ version (5.3) I have de following configuration, on the `activemq.xml` file:

```
<persistenceAdapter>
     <amqPersistenceAdapter syncOnWrite="false" directory="${activemq.base}/data" maxFileLength="20 mb" />
</persistenceAdapter>
```

And now, i am trying to upgrade to version (5.13) and in this configuration it does not have the element `amqPersistenceAdapter` please help me to find and element that I can use in version 5.13

Answer (score 0):

amqPersistenceAdapter was replaced with kahadb over the various ActiveMQ releases since 5.3. So take a look at kahadb in the ActiveMQ documentation how to use and configure it. In fact its configured to use kahadb out of the box, so take a look at the vanilla configuration from the ActiveMQ 5.13 release.

- http://activemq.apache.org/kahadb.html

Comment: Thank you for answer well besides this issue, i have another one.... and i don't know if the problem comes from the activemq.xml or i hava a java class where i am loading the activemq.xml file.. and i am trying to use a PooledConnectionFactory with no succsess in this version and i don't know whether if it comes from activemq.xml or i am doing something wrong on java class